# Automatic expansion of ListView

Tags: android-layout

I'm a facing problem regarding automatic expansion of a ListView ..
1) I had separate xml file for each list item . i.e inflated in an efficient adaptor, list element is also using a selector or highlighter file for background change onClick.

My main xml looks like this

```
-LINEAR LAYOUT - VERTICAL (MAIN)
     - LINEAR LAYOUT - horizontal having 5 buttons.(CHILD 1)
     - LINEAR LAYOUT - horizontal having two views as ListView.
```

The problem i'm facing here is second child having two ListView.. only one ListView is visible and its expanding itself to width as fill parent  .

1) I tried to chnage the list item size .. 
2) Then I tried to customize the ListView size parameters in main xml ,but its cutting the ListView i.e. showing half of the data.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your description, but I think what you're looking for is this:

For each `ListView`, set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_weight="50"`, and on the parent `LinearLayout` set `android:weightSum="100"` and `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.  (The root `LinearLayout` should also have a width of "fill_parent".)  That should cause each child `ListView` to take up half of the screen horizontally.